# Changing number of replicas for an existent bucket in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, buckets

I know is not possible with Couchbase 2.2, but is it possible to change the number of replicas on 2.5 ?
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change the replica count in 2.5 from the web console.  The steps are listed below.

1. Click on the Data Buckets link.
2. Click the arrow to the left of the bucket name to expand the bucket details.
3. Click the Edit button.
4. The replica count appears in the Replicas section.  Change the quantity there.
5. Click Save.
6. Click the Server Nodes link.  After a short time (refresh if necessary), you will see a red message indicating that a rebalance is required.  Rebalance your cluster from the button on that page.  A rebalance is required so that Couchbase can distribute the new set of replica documents across the cluster.

You can also find info about a 'working but not officially supported' way to change the settings in 2.2 at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/couchbase/ClqBDavQIkk.